# Use Azure Active Directory SSO without manually adding users in Active Directory

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I have created an ASP.Net web application that uses Azure AD to authenticate the users.

I have done this in the following steps:

1. Register the App in Azure Active directory
2. Enabled sign in from all work/school accounts and from personal Microsoft accounts.
3. Generate / Configure the ID Token, Client ID, Tenant ID and Redirect URL
4. Deactivated the Multi-Factor authentication (Only password will be sufficient for now).

So far, my app is working fine, but whenever any new user tries to login into the app, After sign in, the authentication screen says

> AADSTS50020: User account  from identity provider
>  does not exist in tenant 'Default Directory' and cannot
> access the application  in that tenant. The account needs to
> be added as an external user in the tenant first. Sign out and sign in
> again with a different Azure Active Directory user account.

To overcome this, First I need to add the user by adding user's email ID in the AD and send an invitation link.

When user uses that invitation link to sign in, then the user is added in the active directory. The the application works fine.

My question is, can we use Azure AD Authentication without the manual intervention of sending the invite link to the user ? Is there any way to auto-add the user based on their domain name or something?

Comment: What's the sign-in URL (i.e. the endpoint for the token request... something like `login.microsoftonline.com`) you have configured in your app?

Answer (score 0):

multi-tenant azure ad app should allow people to login directly without adding them to your own tenant. see an example app we built: https://spring-sso.datawiza.net. you should be able to login via your own Microsoft accounts.